# Input-field, force format 00:00.00

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an input-field that has a value(model) with microseconds(ex. 1950), and a filter that transforms the microseconds to a human readable format, for example 00:19.50(this is displayed in the input-field). How can i validate or force the user to keep this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chive this by making use of the pattern attribute which accepts a  regular expression.

You can read more about it here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

This is the example they provide.

```
<input type="url" name="website" required pattern="https?://.+">
```

I hope this helps.

@gapvision privided you an answer with a correct patter that suit your needs

> pattern='\d\d:\d\d.\d\d

Answer (score 1):

you can specify a `pattern='\d\d:\d\d:\d\d'`:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d\d:\d\d:\d\d" required>
```

For browser support, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: how does this not provide an answer?